# passing a python logger instance as a stream

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

***tl;dr*** how do I pass a [`logging.Logger`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger) instance as a "stream" (similar to `sys.stdout`) that logs a message for each line of text received?

I'm using the `invoke` module [`Runner.run` method](https://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/stable/api/runners.html#invoke.runners.Runner.run) to run a program `/usr/bin/printf`. The `run` method has a parameter `out_stream`. The docs for `Runner.run` read:

> `run(command: str, **kwargs: Any) → Optional[invoke.runners.Result]`
>
> Execute command, returning an instance of Result once complete.
>
> `out_stream` – A file-like stream object to which the subprocess’ standard output should be written. If `None` (the default), `sys.stdout` will be used.

The call to `run` looks like:

```python
import invoke


def print_foobar(context: invoke.context):
    context.run("/usr/bin/printf foobar")
```

I want to pass a `Logger` instance as the `out_stream` like this (pseudo-code):

```python
import invoke
import logging


log = logging.getLogger()

def print_foobar(context: invoke.context):
    context.run("/usr/bin/printf foobar", out_stream=log.stream)
```

I want the standard out of the child process `printf` to be logged by `Logger` instance `log`. Maybe one `log.info` message per line of text from the `printf` child process, or something like that. In other words, how do I get something like a `log.stream` shown in the prior code snippet?

How can I use the `Logger` instance as a "*file-like stream object*" that logs a message for each line of text received?

Comment: Create a class with a `write` method on it, which delegates to `logging.info`.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate; what I have there is the best I can find at the moment but it should be possible to find better. But yes, it's exactly as @PeterWood says. If that isn't enough of a hint, you'll need to ask a more specific question, after making an attempt. You may also find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657820 insightful, although this is meant more for *input* streams.

Comment: "_This is definitely a duplicate_" This question not a duplicate of [Creating a stream class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558622/creating-a-stream-class-in-python). This question also asks about a line-oriented mechanism for the passed `Logger` instance.  Secondly, Peter Wood's hint "_Create a class with a write method on it_" has no necessary relationship with the other questions' Answer of using the `io` module.

"_you'll need to ask a more specific question_" this **is** a very specific question.

Comment: There's a recipe here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#how-to-treat-a-logger-like-an-output-stream

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon look at Peter Wood's *other* comment, which links to a recipe in the Python logging documentation (the logging cookbook).